# ASP.NET Index method not being called after return view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

So I'm pretty new to ASP.Net and I'm having some issues. The problem is when I want to call upon a new controller and show the corresponding view, the index method in that controller does not get activated.

I have this code in my LoginController (I know this is insecure):

```
public ActionResult LoginTest(string inputEmail, string inputPassword, string submit)
{
    if(submit != null)
    {
        Session["email"] = inputEmail;
        return View("~/Views/Home/index.cshtml");                
    }
    return null;
}
```

And this is the code in the controller/view I'm calling (HomeController):

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    if(Session["email"] != null)
    {
        ViewBag.HelloWorld = Session["email"].ToString();
    } else
    {
        ViewBag.HelloWorld = "Does not work.";
    }
    return View();
}
```

Am I not supposed to do this through return View()? Is there a method that calls the controller which calls the corresponding view?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`RedirectToAction`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction(v=vs.118).aspx) in your `LoginController` instead of `return View("~/Views/Home/index.cshtml");`:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Index");
```